# Is this bell circuit safe?

Tags: safety

I have an old-fashioned doorbell (like this one: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c1/DoorBell_001.jpg)[image]

Is it safe to connect it directly to a power supply (I am using a ac/dc converter) or does it need a resistor?

Comment: that bell looks like the spring tension and gap can be adjusted to get it to work over a range of different voltages. I had one similar to that that would run OK of 6V and louder off 12V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a battery operated (DC) rather than transformer operated (AC) bell. Start off by hooking it up to a 6 V or 9 V supply for a couple of seconds and see what happens.

You don't neeed a series resistor if your supply voltage is right. The coil resistance will limit the current.

Comment: Ok, thanks. The power supply I am using takes mains AC supply and transforms it to 5VDC.

Comment: Hook it up! If 5 V isn't enough you'll see the armature pull in a little but not hit the bell and, maybe, not break the internal contact to let it spring back out again.